# How to get the maximum value in a matrix and its row number

Tags: python, indexing, max

I would like to get the maxim value of a matrix and just its row position in the matrix. How to do that?
Thanks again.

I can get the maximum value in the matrix with the following code; but, I am not sure how to get its row index position. To be noticed that the matrix could also has equal values for each row.

```
ratio =[[0.01556884 0.01556884]
 [0.1290337  0.1290337 ]
 [0.07015939 0.07015939]
 [0.12288323 0.12288323]]
        dup = []
        for k in ratio:
            for i in k:
                dup.append(i)

print(max(dup))

0.1290337
```

I expect to obtain the maximum value that I already had, 
0.129037 
and position 1

Could someone help me, to have the row position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a naive implementation using a double for loop.

```
ratio = [[0.01556884, 0.01556884],
         [0.1290337, 0.1290337 ],
         [0.07015939, 0.07015939],
         [0.12288323, 0.12288323]]

max_val = ratio[0][0]
max_loc = (0,0)
for i, row in enumerate(ratio):
    for j, idx in enumerate(row):
        if ratio[i][j] > max_val:
            max_val = ratio[i][j]
            max_loc = (i, j)

print(f"max value {max_val} at {max_loc}")
```

Outputs:

```
max value 0.1290337 at (1, 0)
```

There is no reason to copy the values into a new array. If you are already iterating through the nested list, then just keep track of the index and max value instead.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have your data in a nested Python list, you can do it with a generator like this:

```
ratio =[[0.01556884, 0.01556884],
        [0.1290337,  0.1290337 ],
        [0.07015939, 0.07015939],
        [0.12288323, 0.12288323]]
max_val, row_max, col_max = max((value, i, j)
                                for i, row in enumerate(ratio)
                                for j, value in enumerate(row))
print(f'Max value: ratio[{row_max}][{col_max}] = {max_val}')
# Max value: ratio[1][1] = 0.1290337
```

If you have a NumPy array, then you can do:

```
import numpy as np

ratio = np.array([[0.01556884, 0.01556884],
                  [0.1290337,  0.1290337 ],
                  [0.07015939, 0.07015939],
                  [0.12288323, 0.12288323]])
row_max, col_max = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(ratio), ratio.shape)
max_val = ratio[row_max, col_max]
print(f'Max value: ratio[{row_max}][{col_max}] = {max_val}')
# Max value: ratio[1][0] = 0.1290337
```

Note the different answers due to two array positions containing the maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job quite nicely (your original `ratio` matrix was missing some commas):

```
ratio = [[0.01556884, 0.01556884],
         [0.1290337,  0.1290337],
         [0.07015939, 0.07015939],
         [0.12288323, 0.12288323]]

max_val = 0
idx = None

for i, row in enumerate(ratio):
    if max(row) > max_val:
        max_val = max(row)
        idx = i

print(f"max value: {max_val}, at row: {idx}")
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> max value: 0.1290337, at row: 1
> ```

Or the same little bit more concisely:

```
ratio = [[0.01556884, 0.01556884],
         [0.1290337,  0.1290337],
         [0.07015939, 0.07015939],
         [0.12288323, 0.12288323]]

idx, max_val = max(enumerate(map(max, ratio)), key=lambda x: x[1])

print(f"max value: {max_val}, at row: {idx}")
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> max value: 0.1290337, at row: 1
> ```

Comment: @chrisis Is there a reason you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use `max` and `enumerate`:

```
ratio =[[0.01556884, 0.01556884], [0.1290337,  0.1290337 ],[0.07015939, 0.07015939],[0.12288323, 0.12288323]]

print(max(enumerate(map(max, ratio)), key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

Results:

```
(1, 0.1290337)
```